# Issue with SKSpriteNode moving out of parent's boundary when user moves quickly

Tags: ios, touch, sprite-kit, game-physics

I have an `SKSpriteNode` as my main character with a `PhysicsBody` enabled. My scene also has a `PhysicsBody` applied to contain the main character within the view. Using a `PanGesture` or `touch and drag` type control on the character, I can move the character around the scene without any issue.

The problem is that if I move my finger very quickly, for example: a sharp swipe to the edge of the view, the character can break the `PhysicsBody` of the scene causing it to go off screen. In my game logic, going off screen ends the game, so this is unacceptable.

So how do I keep the `SKSpriteNode` contained to the scene's view at a potentially high user input speeds?

Note: I have also tried enabling `usesPreciseCollisionDetection` to the character sprite, but this doesn't seem to make a difference.

This issue has been replicated in both the simulator as well as live testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common fix for this is to instead of using an edgebased shape for the boundary of your scene, then make four square bodies surrounding your scene. The larger your blocks are the faster you'd need to move to pass through it.